# No sound with Waveshare WM8960 Audio HAT

Tags: audio, pi-zero

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero running Raspberry Pi OS 10 (buster). I have connected a Waveshare WM8960 Audio HAT but am not getting any audible sound from it.

The driver seems to be installed correctly

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dkms status
wm8960-soundcard, 1.0, 5.4.72+, armv6l: installed
```

and the sound card is recognised

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: b1 [bcm2835 HDMI 1], device 0: bcm2835 HDMI 1 [bcm2835 HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 4/4
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
card 1: Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones], device 0: bcm2835 Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones]
  Subdevices: 4/4
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
card 2: wm8960soundcard [wm8960-soundcard], device 0: bcm2835-i2s-wm8960-hifi wm8960-hifi-0 [bcm2835-i2s-wm8960-hifi wm8960-hifi-0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I try to play a WAV file through the sound card, and it appears to be working (i.e. no error messages) but I don't hear any sound.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo aplay -D hw:2,0 Music/Wav_868kb.wav 
Playing WAVE 'Music/Wav_868kb.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo
```

I've tried with different audio files and with different output devices (the speakers that came with the sound card and a pair of headphones), but I still get no sound. I have tried turning up the levels in the alsamixer, but this made no difference.

I've read that having pulseaudio installed can cause issues, but as far I can see I don't have it installed

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pulseaudio --version
bash: pulseaudio: command not found
```

I have found information on similar issues online, but nothing that could fix my problem. I'm very new to both Pi and Linux, so I have no idea what to do from here. Can anyone help resolve this?